# AWS App Runner health check fails on port 80 for Python app

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-app-runner

I have Python app that process data and I am running it in Docker. Locally, it is working fine. When I tried for a first time to run on AWS App Runner I needed health check, so I expose 80 port in Dockerfile and install nginx that listen on that port. When I run container locally I can access the nginx homepage. With curl as well. Here is in addition my Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.9

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

RUN  apt update &&  apt install nginx -y
COPY default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


COPY . .
EXPOSE 80/tcp
COPY start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/start.sh"]type here
```

I was trying to setup health check in AWS App Runner. I am using TCP check on port 80. For some reasons it is failing all the time.

Here is the setup for AWS App Runner:
Source: Private ECR
Deployment Settings: Manual
Port: 80
Auto Scaling: Default
Health Check: TCP (I tried various settings without success)
Security: Use an AWS-owned key (no Instance role)
Networking: Public access

Could you please give me some suggestions what could be the issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like AWS App Runner is the wrong service for you to be using, since you are processing data, instead of hosting a web app. I suggest switching to ECS Scheduled Tasks on Fargate.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the health check is configured to the same port on which the application runs. It's unclear if that is port 80 or not.

Can you check if the application is showing any errors in AWS or has started up correctly?

Can you reach the application directly, when a health check is not configured?

My assumption is that there is something wrong with the application itself and not with the health-check.

Comment: There is not a way to skip health check or to see application logs, except standard output that the deployment is failed.

Comment: Aha! Deployment has failed, that is a different error as the one you have described in the question (health check has failed). Please try to be descriptive and accurate. --- What is the deployment error?